# Counting Distinct Values of Combined Attributes

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with a lot of columns, and I want to count the different combinations of two columns KEY, and SOURCE.
Why can't I use this code:

```
COUNT(KEY, SOURCE) as cnt
```

How can I do it?

Btw, this is only one attribute in the query.
THe query structure is

```
Select
     Attr_1,...Attr_N,
     Measure_1...
     COUNT(KEY, SOURCE) as cnt
     Measure__N
FROM ...
Group BY  Attr_1,...Attr_N
```

And I am using Teradata.

Comment: Use the teradata equivalent of `CONCAT(KEY, SOURCE)` before counting

Comment: Doesn't work in all cases. 'ab' || 'cd'  is equal to 'abc' || 'd'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to do this is to concatenate the strings together with a separator:

```
select . . ., count(distinct concat(key, ':', source)) as numcombos
```

This is not perfect.  For instance, it may not handle `NULL` values the way you want them to.  And, this assumes that the columns don't contain a colon (although a less common character or combination of characters -- such as `'|'` -- could also be used).

Comment: I analysed one example, and it does the count, but not correctly.
Namely, I have 19 rows with the same value, and instead of returning 1, it returns 19.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Adam . . . Are you sure you are using `count(distinct)`?  Are you sure the values are really different?  You need to look at both columns.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT 
                                                CAST(t1.Party_KEY AS CHAR(20))
                                                ||
                                                ':'
                                                ||
                                                CAST( t1.Quelle_TXT AS CHAR(20))
                                                
                ), and the result is 19 instead of 1. I checked it out - the subquery returns 19 rows with the same values in the two columns and in the combined column... No idea what to do next...

Comment: Use `varchar()` instead of `char()`.  The padding of spaces at the end could be causing a problem, although I am not quite sure how this would result in 19 rather than 1.

Comment: sorry, it was my fault - the original query was correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
     KEY,
     SOURCE,
     COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM ...
Group BY KEY, SOURCE
```

Comment: the thing is - the COUNT in question is one attribute in a large query (as I wrote in the question - see the query structure).
Therefore, this is "only" one piece of an information, and I need to integrate it somehow in the query. Any other suggestions?